# How can I use N' ' in Linq to Entity for Non Unicode characters?

Tags: c#, t-sql, linq-to-entities

How can I use N'' in Linq to Entity for example in T-SQL we had this code :

```
select *from students where name=N'سیروان عفیفی'
```

i have this code :

```
var query = from p in dbContext.Students
                            where p.Name == "سیروان عفیفی"
                            select p;
```

how can i do this with Linq to Entity?

i found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.asnonunicode.aspx)  :

```
 var query = (from p in dbContext.Students
                             where p.Name == EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode("سیروان عفیفی")
                            select p);
```

But it's not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the generated query? Can you post it too?

Comment: can you try `EntityFunctions.AsUnicode` instead?

Comment: @w0lf it's for unicode character.

Comment: if the Name property in the model is marked as Unicode you should get the N'' in the query. Also note that in C# characters are Unicode by design: "The char keyword is used to declare an instance of the System.Char structure that represents a Unicode character" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx

Comment: @Pawel how can i get the N'' in query?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi - isn't it already there? Check the SQL Query generated from your linq query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column type is started with 'n' like `nvarchar` or `nchar` then you don't need to add `N"` at the first of your value.

I've tried the following and it worked with `nvarchar`

```
x.Name == "سیروان عفیفی"
```